# Trying to deploy traefik with kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, traefik, rbac

I'm trying to deploy traefik in Kubernetes with minikube. The deployment works well, the pod starts but when I look into pod logs, I get this :

```
Failed to list *v1beta1.Ingress: the server could not find the requested resource (get ingresses.extensions)
```

My current kubectl & kubernetes server versions are :

```
kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"22", GitVersion:"v1.22.1", GitCommit:"632ed300f2c34f6d6d15ca4cef3d3c7073412212", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-08-19T15:45:37Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.7", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"22", GitVersion:"v1.22.1", GitCommit:"632ed300f2c34f6d6d15ca4cef3d3c7073412212", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-08-19T15:39:34Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.7", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"
```

The version of traefik image that I try to deploy : **traefik:v2.0**

I set up all the RBAC resources and my current configuration for traefik is :

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: IngressClass
metadata:
  name: traefik-lb
spec:
  controller: traefik.io/ingress-controller
---
apiVersion: "networking.k8s.io/v1"
kind: "Ingress"
metadata:
  name: "example-ingress"
spec:
  ingressClassName: "traefik-lb"
  rules:
  - host: "*.example.com"
    http:
      paths:
      - path: "/example"
        pathType: Exact
        backend:
          service:
            name: "rabbitmq"
            port:
                number: 32666
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: traefik-ingress-controller
rules:
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: [services, endpoints]
    verbs: [list, watch]
  - apiGroups: [extensions]
    resources: [ingresses]
    verbs: [list]
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: traefik-ingress-controller
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: traefik-ingress-controller
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: {{ include "traefik.serviceAccountName" . }}
  namespace: default
```

The command api-versions result :

```
d3vpasha@d3vpasha-ZenBook-UX425EA-UX425EA ~/helm-charts/charts/traefik (dev)$ kubectl api-versions
admissionregistration.k8s.io/v1
apiextensions.k8s.io/v1
apiregistration.k8s.io/v1
apps/v1
authentication.k8s.io/v1
authorization.k8s.io/v1
autoscaling/v1
autoscaling/v2beta1
autoscaling/v2beta2
batch/v1
batch/v1beta1
certificates.k8s.io/v1
coordination.k8s.io/v1
discovery.k8s.io/v1
discovery.k8s.io/v1beta1
events.k8s.io/v1
events.k8s.io/v1beta1
flowcontrol.apiserver.k8s.io/v1beta1
networking.k8s.io/v1
node.k8s.io/v1
node.k8s.io/v1beta1
policy/v1
policy/v1beta1
rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
scheduling.k8s.io/v1
storage.k8s.io/v1
storage.k8s.io/v1beta1
v1
```

I don't see what I do wrong :/ if someone can help me, thank you in advance

EDIT : I would like to add the fact that traefik:2.5 has not this problem so it's something related to the version 2.0 of traefik...

Comment: It seems that your cluster does not have the API that it is requesting, i.e. `ingresses.extensions`. Can you update the question with `kubectl api-versions`?

Comment: @MarkoE I updated my question with the result of the command, thanks for your time

Comment: I don't see `extensions/v1beta1` API in your cluster, so that could be the reason why the Ingress is not working, as it is probably in that API namespace. You can check in more detail if there is a line `ingresses  ing  extensions/v1beta1  true  Ingress` by running `kubectl api-resources`.

Comment: So, my cluster is 1.21. It seems that the APIs have been deprecated in 1.22: https://kubernetes.io/blog/2021/07/14/upcoming-changes-in-kubernetes-1-22/#api-changes. There is an explanation on that page what to do with your resources, but in short it should be migrated to `networking.k8s.io.v1`.

Comment: @MarkoE The problem does not come from the Ingress resources that I create because the kind that I use is networking.k8s.io/v1 & not networking.k8s.io/v1beta1. The problem is with the configuration file of Traefik. In fact, I declare in traefik.toml : [kubernetes] to tell it that I will use kubernetes as ingress controller & that makes the problem because I think traefik is looking by default for v1beta1 version of ingress but that doesn't actually exist in my system since it's deprecated like you said. Do you have any idea how to resolve the issue ? Thank you again

Comment: Yeah, I realized that you are already using the latest version of the API. I am not sure how exactly Traefik works, but maybe this can help: https://github.com/traefik/traefik/blob/v2.0/docs/content/providers/kubernetes-ingress.md#traefik--kubernetes. I see the 2.0 version references `extensions/v1beta1` while in 2.5 it's using the `networking.k8s.io.v1`, so not sure if this will help at all.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at a lot of examples that I have done for the same [here](https://github.com/codeaprendiz/devops-essentials/tree/main/home/container-orchestration/kubernetes)

Try [this](https://github.com/codeaprendiz/devops-essentials/tree/main/home/container-orchestration/kubernetes/practice-tasks/task-aws-010-deploy-treafik-kops-k8s-helm). You might need to change the service type from LoadBalancer to ClusterIP.

This might help as well [traefik-whoami](https://github.com/codeaprendiz/devops-essentials/tree/main/home/container-orchestration/kubernetes/practice-tasks/task-gcp-023-traefik-whoami)

Try using helm for generating resources. Its much more convenient to manage.
You can always generate the k8s-manifests if something is wrong.

Comment: All links are broken

Comment: How about now? Thank you for informing. I have been restructuring the repo. @EugeneLebedev

Comment: Thanks for quick response, problem has been solved